# Windows corrupted icons

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, filesystem-corruption

I don't know why, but a bunch of systems icons seem to be corrupted. I've tried to clear icons cache (Explorer folder, etc...), enable the options in the Advanced System Settings, repair Windows with Media Creation Tool, and I don't know what to do next.

Here some screenshots of what I see:

*Restart and update* button from the Start menu:

[image: "Restart and update" button from the start menu]

"Phone Link" app from the Microsoft Store:

[image: "Your Phone" app from the Microsoft Store]
([App link in case you don't see what app I'm talking about](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/your-phone/9nmpj99vjbwv))

Windows 10 Professional - Version 21H1 - Build 19043.1288- Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0 (I don't know what experience it is, but I never joined it)

AMD Ryzen 5 5600X - MSI MPG B550 GAMING PLUS - EVGA RTX 2080 Ti FTW3 - CORSAIR 16GO 3200MHZ (all drivers and updates done, as I know)

Comment: `chkdsk c: /f /r /x` - then restart the computer

Comment: @shawn Didn't work :(

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image

Comment: Try DISM / SFC.:  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  followed by SFC /SCANNOW  If no, more aggressive repairs are needed